# how to apply window function in python?

Tags: pandas, window

I have below sample dataframe as :- i.e. id, name across different year and quater with different value

```
id name year quater value 
1  bn   2017 2
1  bn   2017 3     4.5
1  bn   2017 4
2  an   2018 1     2.3   
2  an   2018 2     3.3
2  an   2018 3     4.5
```

I have to identify if the name+id(primary key)
 has appeared before in the year and quater that has value then treat that as existing(0) and if there is value in the future and nothing before then treat it as new(1).

```
id name year quater value status
1  bn   2017 2            1
1  bn   2017 3     4.5    0
1  bn   2017 4            0
2  an   2018 1     2.3    1 
2  an   2018 2     3.3    0
2  an   2018 3     4.5    0
```

Comment: You say *has appeared before in the year and quater* but your output seems to be only that the name has appeared in the year?

Answer (score 1):

I believe need [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with invert boolean mask by `~` and cast to `integer`:

```
df['status'] = (~df['name'].duplicated()).astype(int)
#if multiple columns
#df['status'] = (~df.duplicated(['id','name'])).astype(int)
print (df)
   id name  year  quater  value  status
0   1   bn  2017       2    NaN       1
1   2   an  2018       1    2.3       1
2   2   an  2018       2    3.3       0
3   2   an  2018       3    4.5       0
```

Comment: this is not correct, i changed the data bit to explain it better, please cld u help

Comment: @user3222101 - Not 100% sure, but need `(df.duplicated(['id','name', 'year','quater'], keep=False) | ~df.duplicated(['id','name', 'year'])).astype(int)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `duplicated` with a subset of id, name and year, then invert the result to identify the first occurrence..., eg:

```
df['status'] = (~df.duplicated(subset=['id', 'name', 'year'])).astype(int)
```

Gives you:

```
   id name  year  quater  value  status
0   1   bn  2017       2    NaN       1
1   2   an  2018       1    2.3       1
2   2   an  2018       2    3.3       0
3   2   an  2018       3    4.5       0
```

Note that while this'll work on your data ordered as presented you may wish to sort by year (and maybe quarter) to ensure your status flags go within the same year and to the first quarter seen appropriately.

Comment: this is not correct, i changed the data bit to explain it better, please cld u help

Comment: @user3222101 how does that extra row get in your output exactly? You're going to need to explain that...

Comment: @user3222101 right... but then you do get the result you're after - why is it not correct?